# isRegistered() vs. isRegisteredOnServer()

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

> isRegisteredOnServer()
>
> Checks whether the device was successfully registered in the server side

Does the new GCM `isRegisteredOnServer()` check whether the app is registered on GCM or on the 3rd party server? What is the difference between `isRegistered()` and `isRegisteredOnServer()`?

If `isRegisteredOnServer()` checks in the third party server, how will it do in third party server? Is there any specific function to be implemented in third party server as well?

Comment: So, am I understanding correctly that isRegisteredOnServer() does not actually ping the 3rd party server at all? It's looking like the only time the 3rd party server is called for the basic GCM setup is to send the "register" or "unregister" messages. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`isRegistered()` returns whether or not the application / device pair is registered on GCM.

`isRegisteredOnServer()` returns whether or not you've sent the registration ID to your server. It knows this because you'll have called `setRegisteredOnServer()` after successfully doing so.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true)`, it saves on the Google server that you took care of registering this user on your back-end server (the server will post msg to Google server)

When you call `GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false)`, it deletes the flag.

`isRegisteredOnServer()` is used to query this property.

Hope this help.

Comment: Based on `setRegisteredOnServer` implementation, this method does not send a message to the Google server, but only stores the state in a preference file.